# Type error in Python: need a single Unicode character as parameter

Tags: python, unicode, numeric

When I try to convert a unicode variable to float using `unicodedata.numeric(variable_name)`, I get this error "need a single Unicode character as parameter". Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Here is the code snippet I'm using :

```
f = urllib.urlopen("http://compling.org/cgi-bin/DAL_sentence_xml.cgi?sentence=good")
s = f.read()
f.close()
doc = libxml2dom.parseString(s)
measure = doc.getElementsByTagName("measure")
valence = unicodedata.numeric(measure[0].getAttribute("valence"))        
activation = unicodedata.numeric(measure[0].getAttribute("activation"))
```

This is the error I'm getting when I run the code above

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sentiment.py", line 61, in <module>
valence = unicodedata.numeric(measure[0].getAttribute("valence"))        
TypeError: need a single Unicode character as parameter
```

Comment: Please post the exact code you are using and the complete error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary:** Use `float()` instead.

The `numeric` function takes a **single** character.  It does not do general conversions:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.numeric('½')
0.5
>>> unicodedata.numeric('12')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: need a single Unicode character as parameter
```

If you want to convert a number to a `float`, use the `float()` function.

```
>>> float('12')
12.0
```

It won't do that Unicode magic, however:

```
>>> float('½')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '½'
```

Comment: Hmm...so is there a way I can convert the unicode variable I have (which you can see in the code) to a float

Comment: It's worth noting that if you want that magic too, the best route is to try and do one (the common case), and on a ``ValueError``/``TypeError``, do the other.

Comment: @Lattyware: Only that won't handle `3½`, or `三千八百`, or practically anything else.  `float()` is nice and predictable.

Comment: Oh, naturally - it's not a miracle idea or anything, but it could be useful in the odd case. You are right that if you are expecting that kind of incredibly varied input, you are going to need a much more sophisticated parsing function.